# How to Integration Test Broadcast Receiver + Service with new Rule framework or robolectric

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, integration-testing, robolectric

I'm trying to test a started service that will return its results via a local broadcast receiver/intent.

I have that working... but I want to unit/integration test it.

I can find plenty of code on how to do that in the old ApplicationTestCase/etc way, but I can't find a good example of how to do it in the new 'Rule' framework.

Here is the Integration Test I have so far...

```
    LocalBroadcastManager instance = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(
                                           InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
    final boolean[] called = new boolean[1];
    final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            called[0] = true;
        }
    };

    instance.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("com.foo"));
    mServiceRule.startService(serviceIntent);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    assertThat(called[0], is(true));
```

and here is the relevant part of the (this is all a sample project I made to proof of concept how to get this code working) onHandleIntent code:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.foo");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).
             sendBroadcast(returnIntent);
```

Note: I'd even accept a robolectric solution as long as it used the newest 3.2 API  (Need that for API 25 support)

Comment: I wonder what you're trying to test? If you want to test broadcast or service just call them directly in test. If you want to test that Android is starting service or calling the BroadcastReceiver then there is no much value in it. I hope we trust Android team enough to make it happen. You might still have an xml check for proper service and broadcast definition

Comment: I'm testing the service. The service is not bound, and therefore the only way to test it is to receive the sent Intent. It is an IntentService, but I overrode it in the Test directory to have a public onHandleIntent (which DOES run because I can cause null pointer except if I try to.) but I need to return the results back to the app.

Comment: Also, testing that the Intent launched (and that it is launched) by the service upon completion has the proper Action... is a good enough Regression Test in and of itself.

Comment: You're testing a class. You can call any public/protected/package method on it